Break a secondary thread loop immediately depending on the value of a variable set by the main loop
I'm encountering a concurrency problem in C++ that I'm struggling to find the best solution for. I have two threads: one is the main program, and the other is responsible for controlling the lights of my device. Here's the code for my second thread:
void DroneService::setUpLightsMode(LightModes mode){
    this->lightMode = mode;
    k_work_submit(&work_queue);
}

void DroneService::workHandler(struct k_work* work){
    DroneService* droneService = getInstance();

        

    while(droneService->lightMode == Stop){
        droneService->rightLed->syncFadeLed(100, 10, 3000);
        k_msleep(1000);
        droneService->rightLed->syncFadeLed(10, 100, 3000);
        k_msleep(1000);
    } 
    
    if (droneService->lightMode == Running && droneService->pastLightMode != Running){
        LOG_DBG("*************Running\n");
        droneService->pastLightMode = Running;
        droneService->rightLed->syncFadeLed(10, 100, 500);
    }
    
}

You can see that my main thread modifies the mode in which the second thread needs to work through the variable lightMode, but I need to be able to break the loop immediately when lightMode changes to the Running state. Currently, this does not happen because the while loop takes some seconds and only changes to the Running mode when the while loop finishes, can someone help me to find a good solution?
Thank you
I tried breaking the loop in each step of the while but is not fast enough

The answer will very much depend on the exact implementation of k_msleep and syncFadeLed...

The first hit for k_msleep for me is something called "zephyr project", which supports k_poll (struct k_poll_event *events, int num_events, k_timeout_t timeout). If "change lights mode" is an event you can signal, there's your answer.

Use a std::condition_variable. That will also protect your status variable, but more importantly, give you something you can "wait" on. Or, in your case, wait_for -- a variant of the wait call with a timeout. Thus, you can wait_for the status change, or the 1000ms timeout, whichever comes first:
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable condition;
LightModes mode=LightModes::stop;

...

{
   std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
   while (mode==LightModes::stop)
   {
      lock.unlock();
      rightLed->syncFadeLed(100, 10, 3000);

      lock.lock();
      condition.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(1000), [this]() { return mode!=LightModes::stop; });
      if (mode!=LightModes::stop) break;

      lock.unlock();
      rightLed->syncFadeLed(10, 100, 3000);

      lock.lock();
      condition.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(1000), [this]() { return mode!=LightModes::stop; });
   }
}

If you need your syncFadeLed to break as well, add similar checks to whatever it does. You might consider using an exception for this (throwing a "LoopCancel" or something like that), so you don't have to pass result codes through a hierarchy of things.
Also, to change the status, do something like this (you probably want to wrap it into a set() call of some kind):
void set(LightModes new)
{
   {
      std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
      mode=new;
   }
   condition.notify_all();
}

This will set the new status, and then wake up whoever might be waiting for a status change.
And no, C++ does not have an "interrupt" or something like that, where some thread could "interrupt" another, and that interrupted thread would then just get an "IWasInterrupted" exception out of nowhere. That would be nice, but it won't happen :-) One way or another, you have to do such things manually -- all you could do is wrap ideas like the above in separate classes so it's a little less visible/repetitive.

IMO, You have an architectural problem.
I would never dedicate a thread to "animating" any user interface element. I would not do it for a moving object on a screen, and I would not do it for a blinking LED on a hardware device. I would use some kind of a "timer service" instead.
The problem you are facing is that you want to change the state of the LED, but that state is at least partially implicit in the program counter of the thread that animates it. When the light is on, the thread is executing one of the k_msleep(1000); source lines, but when the light is off, the thread is sleeping in a different source line.
IMO, the best way to animate is to have a state object that explicitly represents the desired UI state, and a "event handler" function that, whenever it is called, no matter which thread calls it, sets the physical state of the LED according to the explicit, desired state and the current wall-clock time.

Example:
The desired UI state initially is LED_SLOW_BLINK—one second on, one second off.
The physical state is, the LED is "on." It has been on for 200ms, and in 800ms, the timer will fire, and the handler function will

Look at the wall clock time and the UI state, and infer that the LED is supposed to turn off at that time. So, it will

Change the physical state of the LED to "off," and then

The handler will schedule another timer event, 1000ms further into the future for when the physical state is supposed to change back to "on" again.


BUT
Something happens in some thread t, and now we want the UI state to be LED_OFF. So, how we do it is, thread t changes the state variables, and then thread t directly calls the handler. (Remember, we wrote the handler to be safely callable from any thread.) The handler sees that the desired UI state is LED_OFF and it changes the physical state to match.
The LED immediately turns off.
Meanwhile, the timer still will fire 800ms later, and the handler will be called from the timer thread. What do we do about that?
We do nothing. We let the timer fire. 800ms later, the timer fires, it calls the handler function, and the handler function

Looks at the wall clock time and the UI state as before, and it sees that the LED is supposed to be always off, and so it,

Redundantly sets the physical state of the LED to "off," and then

It just returns. It does not schedule another timer event, because there is no future time when the physical state needs to change.


The LED stays off, and the user never knows that anything happened in the software.

When some thread u wants to change the UI state back to LED_SLOW_BLINK or to LED_FAST_BLINK or to LED_STEADY_ON or whatever, all it does is, it sets the state variable, and then it calls the handler. The handler is responsible for figuring out the appropriate physical state based on the UI state and the clock, and the handler is responsible for scheduling any future timed event if needed.
